# generics: filter a Collection<T> but at the same time bound it to RandomAccess

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Suppose I want to have such a method:

```
private static <T> Collection<T> filter(Collection<T> initial, Predicate<T> predicate){
    //....
}
```

This is trivial.

But, for some reason, I want to take as input not a simple `Collection`, but one that implements `RandomAccess`. So I change the definition to:

```
 private static <T, M extends Collection<T> & RandomAccess> Collection<T> filter(M initial, Predicate<T> predicate){
    return initial.stream()
                  .filter(predicate)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

this works on the declaration, but it would fail for callers. That is:

```
filter(List.of(1,2,3), x -> x > 1); // fails
```

What I find a bit awkward is that the compilation (and thus the resolution of `T`) works if I remove the `& RandomAccess` part:

```
private static <T, M extends Collection<T>> Collection<T> filter(M initial, Predicate<T> predicate){
    ....
}
```

I would understand if the failure would occur if `RandomAccess` would take a type parameter. But it does not, so (at least in my understanding) it should not influence the resolution of `T`.

Is there a way to have such a *compile* time constraint at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would understand if the failure would occur if RandomAccess would take a type parameter. But it does not, so (at least in my understanding) it should not influence the resolution of T.

It does not. The problem with `filter(List.of(1,2,3), x -> x > 1);` is that the static type of the expression `List.of(1,2,3)` is not a subtype of `RandomAccess`, and that's rejected because it does not meet the `extends RandomAccess` constraint.

Both of the following compile with no problem, with the inference of `T` remaining unaffected

```
filter(new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3)), x -> x > 1);
filter(new ArrayList<>(List.of("a", "b", "c")), x -> x.length() > 1);
```

Simply because `ArrayList` is both a `Collection` and `RandomAccess` subtype. I guess, however, that depending on your compiler implementation, you have one of many flavors of unhelpful error messages (like `The method filter(M, Predicate<T>) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (List<Integer>)` on `filter(...)` and `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Integer> to M` on `List.of(...)` in Eclipse)

Comment: `filter((Collection<Integer> & RandomAccess) List.of(1,2,3), x -> x > 1);` works, FYI.

Comment: @Eugene well... try `filter((Collection<Integer> & RandomAccess) new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)), x -> x > 1)`. That cast works because `List.of(1,2,3)` returns a `RandomAccess` type. And thanks to the fact that Java doesn't check casts to interace types at compile time (in cases like that one), you don't get a compile time error, but a class cast exception at runtime.

Comment: right, I know and understand that, but at the same time :  `System.out.println(List.of(1,2,3) instanceof RandomAccess); // true`, so I really do not understand how the "...is that the static type of the expression List.of(1,2,3) is not a subtype of RandomAccess" :|

Comment: @Eugene The return type of `List.of(...)` is `List<...>`. And there is no `RandomAccess` in the type hierarchy of `List` that the compiler would know of (`List<E> -> Collection<E> -> Iterable<E>`). As you know, generic bounds are enforced at compile time (well, unless one uses raw types) and that's based on static types.

Comment: And `new ArrayList<>()` and `List.of()` both work because they return instances of `RandomAccess (`java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.ImmutableCollections.ListN<E>` **do** implement `RandomAccess`)

Comment: I see your point now, yes. This sucks, though. This makes my method useless, since callers can't really pass immutable collections; unless I document that they might need to cast explicitly... thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well, they can... except that the convenience of programming to the `List` interface on your caller side is lost (all that's missing is a convenient `List<T>` to `List<T> & RandomAccess` converter).